# how to get table structure with column name in a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me with the query to get table name,column name , column datatype , isprimary etc in single row .

for eg:
My output of employee table with Columns E_Id,E_Name,E_City should be as below

---

TabName ColumnName datatype isprimary Columnname datatype isprimary Columnname datatype

Employee - E_Id - int - S - E_Name - varchar - N - E_City - varchar

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA system views to get this information for any table.
The following is an example:

```
SELECT 
    c.TABLE_NAME, 
    c.COLUMN_NAME, 
    c.DATA_TYPE, 
    CASE WHEN tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsPrimary
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
    LEFT JOIN (
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu 
        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
        ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
              AND tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = ccu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
              AND tc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = ccu.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
          AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    )
    ON ccu.COLUMN_NAME = c.COLUMN_NAME 
      AND ccu.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME 
      AND ccu.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA 
      AND ccu.TABLE_CATALOG = c.TABLE_CATALOG
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'Employee'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get table schema from the following,

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TABLENAME';
GO
```

(but the output format is not like you want)

source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx